# Threaty safety vs performance in Java and Python

Tags: java, python, multithreading, concurrency

Use case: a single data structure (hashtable, array, etc) whose members are accessed frequently by multiple threads and modified infrequently by those same threads. How do I maintain performance while guaranteeing thread safety (ie, preventing dirty reads).

Java: Concurrent version of the data structure (concurrent hashmap, Vector, etc).

Python: No need if only threads accessing it, because of GIL. If it's multiple processes that will be reading and updating the data structure, then use threading.Lock. Force the each process's code to acquire the lock before and release the lock after accessing the data structure.

Does that sound reasonable? Will Java's concurrent data structure impose too much penalty to read speed? Is there higher level concurrency mechanism in python?

Comment: Locks (which are basically what are used to implement many concurrent structures in Java) don't guarantee thread safety.  They do nothing to prevent deadlock situations, for example.

Comment: You can't share Python higher-level data structures like `dict` and `list` between processes in the first place. You can find libraries on PyPI that give you dict-like and list-like sharable data structures, but you can also find sharable "concurrent" data structures. And, for that matter, you can find persistent (non-mutating) sharable data structures for both languages.

Comment: Also, "How do I maintain performance" usually isn't a matter of how you synchronize your data structures. If you're just trying to optimize _everything_ without knowing what matters, the obvious answer is to never use Python, but the even more obvious answer is that you shouldn't be trying to do that.

Comment: @abarnert good point about not sharing native python data structure between processes. So I'll limit our case to multiple threads accessing it. In that case, my only option is using threading.Lock or RLock? There's no higher level concurrency modules that exist in python ?

Comment: I suggest to ask **one** question per question. Like: asking one question specifically for java, and one for python.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth for simplicity let's leave deadlock prevention out, and just defining thread safe in this case as prevention of dirty reads.

Comment: The real question, as already outlined: you need to put things into perspective. You have a close look at the *real* data, to understand where your *real* bottlenecks are. And then you balance very specific fine tuning of these bottlenecks versus accepting more simple solutions that are not as performant, but easier to maintain over time.

Comment: @GhostCat sure, but let's treat this as simple conceptual exercise without details on the type of data.

Comment: Then it doesn't make sense to talk lengthy about python and java ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166486/discussion-between-user1008636-and-ghostcat).

Comment: If you're sharing native Python data structures between threads (in CPython), the GIL already makes them atomic—as you said in your OP—so why do you think "my only option is threading.Lock or RLock"? But meanwhile, why do you only care about the builtin structures? One of the main reasons to use either Python or Java is the huge ecosystem of high-quality third-party libraries for both.

Comment: Without code, I think this questions is a poor fit for SO.  With code (working code), I think it might be a better fit for the Code Review site.  Either way it's kinda off topic.  I'd suggest one question each on Java and Python with example code on Code Review, ask for critiques there.

Comment: I LOVE the title of this, it's like you care about performance over correctness

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reasoning about performance, I highly recommend to measure it for your application. Don't risk thread problems for a performance improvement that you most probably won't ever notice.

So: write thread-safe code without any performance-tricks, use a decent profiler to find the percentage of time spent inside the data structure access, and then decide if that part is worth any improvement.

I bet there will be other bottlenecks, not the shared data structure.

If you like, come back to us with your code and the profiler results.